# An error always occurs when starting RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When I open RStudio, an error saying that:

```
Error: 1:6: unexpected input
1: setwd（
^
```

always occurs in the console.
I tried some solutions online, and I have removed all the .RData files, but it still occurs in the console. How to solve this problem?

I tried to delete all the .RData files.

Comment: Do you have a .Rhistory file also? If so, remove it and see if something changes.

Comment: Maybe you should say what you tried so we don’t have to repeat them?

Comment: Do you use a global or personal .Renviron or .Rprofile file? Looks like a try to set the working directory somewhere but there is a space between setwd and the opening (

Comment: Check for respective entries in `Rprofile.site` file. On Linus it's located in `/etc/R/Rprofile.site`.